# How to display both raw and percent in Venn diagram

Tags: r, plot, annotations, partitioning, venn-diagram

I am plotting a Venn diagram using the function `draw.triple.venn()` `library(VennDiagram)`. This is my code in R:

```
g = draw.triple.venn(area1 = 4.1, area2 = 5.6, area3 = 15.9, n12 = 1.3, n23 = 4.2, n13 = 2.3, n123 = 1.2, category = c("Landuse", "Environment", "Space"), fill = c("darkgray", "gray", "lightgrey"), print.mode = c("percent", "percent", "percent"), sigdig=2, ind = T)
grid.arrange(gTree(children=g))
```

This is the current figure:

[image]

Now, I would like to display both 'percentage' and 'raw' for each fraction. In the package description it states: 'print.mode' can be either 'raw' or 'percent'. This is the format that the numbers will be printed in. Can pass in a vector with the second element being printed under the first.

This seems to suggest that both 'raw' and 'percent' can be displayed together. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Also, how can I control that number of digits is used consistently, i.e. have 56.0% (rather than 56%) and 0.5% (rather than 0.53%)? I have set sigdig=2 which I thought would force consistency in that space.

Moreover, is there a way to control the fill colour of each fraction (as compared to only a vector of 3 colours)?

Finally, is there any way to add text manually? I would like to note the proportion of residual variation in the bottom left corner.

This is a link to the package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/VennDiagram.pdf

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: *Any suggestions on how to do this?* : `print.mode = c("raw", "percent")` seems to work. *Finally, is there any way to add text manually?* : `grid::grid.text("some label", x=0.1, y=0.1)` . *Moreover, is there a way to control the fill colour of each fraction* not easily , I think, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963293/how-to-define-color-of-intersection-in-a-venn-diagram shows one way.

Comment: Concerning adding text: did you run the code in the right order? As also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281140/grid-text-and-positioning-in-viewports#20281316), you need to first run `grid.arrange(gTree(children=g))` or whichever way you print the plot, and then run 'grid::grid.text("some label", x=0.1, y=0.1)'. If I run your code, plus the grid.text bit in this way, it nicely shows "some label" in the bottom left corner of the plot.

Comment: As you have suggested, I had to reverse the order. Thanks for the code and for spotting my error.

Comment: ps... you do not need `grid.arrange(gTree(children=g))`, simply, `grid::grid.draw(g)` will do. (and use `grid::grid.newpage()` for a new plot), although i think triple.venn draws automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `print.mode = c("raw", "percent")` works to include both raw and percent values.

Function `grid::grid.text("some label", x=0.1, y=0.1)` works to add text manually.